# Android Jellybean app encryption works on other versions?

Tags: android, encryption, android-4.2-jelly-bean

so... i read jellybean update note and saw "Jelly Bean introduces app encryption for paid apps. "

as far as my understanding goes, this service supposed to make application unusable when someone move its apk to another device.

but what about non-jellybean androids?
if someone moves apk from jellybean device to ICS device, would this encryption function still work?

Answer (score 1):

Google noted in Google IO 2012 keynote, it should not affect exsitting devices, but who knows, here is a link that report lots of app break by this.

http://www.androidpolice.com/2012/08/08/jelly-bean-app-encryption-breaks-thousands-of-apps-in-the-play-store-google-disables-drm-for-now/

seems it was disable for now...

Comment: if it does not affect existing devices, does this means you could arbitrarily disable encryption by moving apk files to devices with lower version of Android?

Comment: i read reports talking about app breaks but none of them mentioned anything about compatibility of such function. i mailed this question to google play team but haven't heard from them yet..